# Formatting a csv file

Tags: python, dataframe, formatting

I have a csv file with no formatting. I need to format the csv file.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('abc.csv')
df['speed'] = df['speed'].map('{:06,.2f}'.format)
df.to_csv("FINAL.csv")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2009, in map
mapped = map_f(values, arg)
File "pandas\src\inference.pyx", line 1064, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:58525)
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

For Example:

```
df['speed'] = [54,156,3]
```

Expected output:

```
speed
054.00
156.00
003.00
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the comma in your string formatting and it should work.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([54,156,3])
df[0].map('{:06.2f}'.format)
```

output:

```
054.00
156.00
003.00
```

Here's a reasource for string formatting:

https://pyformat.info/

Edit:
It sounds like this is a problem of messy data. I suggest trying the following options when reading your csv file:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('abc.csv', dtype=object)
df['speed'] = df['speed'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df['speed'] = df['speed'].map('{:06.2f}'.format)
```

`errors='coerce'` will try to convert to float, and return `NaN` if it fails to do so.

Comment: Even though I remove the comma (,) I get the same error.

Comment: can you try the same thing, importing values from a csv file?

Comment: From the edits, it looks like you get a different error. `ValueError: Invalid conversion specification` changed to `ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'`. Make sure your values are being read in as float. Try `pd.to_numeric()`

Comment: The csv file actually contains multiple columns. The first column can be converted to the specified format for some reason. If I try to run the same code in a different column, I get the same error.

Comment: Can a dataframe have different columns with different formatting?

Comment: Yes, every column has it's own [dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html). In fact, if your csv is really messy you can have different types for each element, the columns `dtype` will be listed as `object`.